# How can I query Active Directory Sites and Services in c#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I don't know if I'm using the wrong search terms, but I can't find a decent example of this anywhere.

I'd like to query a specific AD site and return the computer names inside of it in c#.

I've tried this without luck

```
ActiveDirectorySiteCollection coll = new ActiveDirectorySiteCollection("ad site name");
```

And visual studio tells me it doesn't take a constructor with a single argument?

Comment: You start with a [DirectoryContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.directorycontext?view=netframework-4.8) object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ActiveDirectorySite.FindByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectorysite.findbyname) to find a specific site, then look at the [`Servers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectorysite.servers) property. For example:

```
var context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Forest);
var site = ActiveDirectorySite.FindByName(context, "SiteName");

foreach (DirectoryServer server in site.Servers) {
    Console.WriteLine(server.Name);
}
```

If you don't know the name of the site, you can look up all the sites in your forest like this:

```
var forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();

foreach (ActiveDirectorySite site in forest.Sites) {
    Console.WriteLine(site.Name);
}
```

Comment: To add to this, I found a powershell example as well


   $domain = "xxx.xxx";
   $adSite = "xxx";
   $context = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext("domain",$domain);
   $dom = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($context);
   $domainSpecificDCs = $dom.FindAllDomainControllers($adSite);